# MySQL max value for each condition

Tags: mysql, max

I'd like to select the max value of a column for a specific type of data in my table.

For a simplified example, let's say I have a game with Girl and Boy players. I want to be able to retrieve the highest scores where gender = girl and where gender = boy with a single query.

Any way to do this? Obviously for this example you could just do two queries, but the data in my app is a lot more complicated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your example will be develop in this simple way:

```
SELECT gender, MAX(score)
FROM players
GROUP BY gender
```

I suppose you have a table PLAYERS, where you store the score and the gender.

If you have other more complex situation, yuo must write here and then we can analyze your case.

Comment: Ah it was so frigging obvious. Thanks, having a massive brain block at the minute.

Comment: Don't worry. If can I help you, I'll try! ;) Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

This kind of stuff ?

```
SELECT gender, MAX(score) as highscore
FROM players
GROUP BY gender;
```

Comment: You're right, thanks. Unfortunately the other guy answered at exactly the same time and he looks to have fewer points than you, so I think I'll give him the tick. Really appreciate the help though :)